# Can you pass commands to a VM from the host server?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have written a batch file to set the IP address of a host server and the two virtual machines running on it. At the moment you have to copy the script onto each machine and run it which isn't what I want, I would like to run the script on the host server and have the commands passed to each VM.

Is this possible?

Comment: What does the server and VMs run?

Comment: what commands do you want to pass?

Comment: The host and one of the VM's runs Server 2012 R2 and the other VM is Windows 7.
I want to be able to set either a static IP or set them to take DHCP.

Comment: The first three octets need to be a variable which will be passed from a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this with the use of PowerShell Sessions.

Firstly, Enable PowerShell Remoting.  To do this, open PowerShell as an administrator and run `enable-psremoting -force`.

Anything you declare locally can be passed into a session using a syntax similar to the following:

```
$a = 1
$b = 2
New-PSSession -ComputerName MyRemoteMachineName | Out-Null
Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ArgumentList($a, $b) -ScriptBlock {
    $args[0]
    $args[1]
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

[image]

By declaring variables and passing them into a session commands "Argument List", they are passed into the remote session in order.  In this case:
`ArgumentList($a, $b)` becomes `$args[0]` & `$args[1]`.  A 3rd variable could have become `$ags[2]` (and so on).

---

retrieving from a session is equally as simple - with the following:

```
$myString = "Something"
New-PSSession -ComputerName MyRemoteComputerName | Out-Null
$outputFromSession = Invoke-Command -Session (Get-PSSession) -ArgumentList($myString) -ScriptBlock {
    $args[0] + " " +  $env:COMPUTERNAME
}
$outputFromSession
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

[image]

By assigning the variable `$outputFromSession` to capture anything returned - this is passed back from the remote session to the local one and can then be used later on and elsewhere if needed.

Easy as that :)

Ben